# Dart command line app on Windows, can't import packages

Tags: command-line, dart, package

I'm on Windows 10 and I'm following this tutorial: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/cmdline/

However, it seems it cannot use packages as per below output. Am I missing something, or is this a known issue on Windows? I installed dart using choco and it added dart's location to my path.

I was able to make it work by copying the packages junction (symbolic link or shortcut maybe?) that WebStorm created for some project and pasting it next to this dart file. But I don't think it's what we're supposed to do.

How can we make sure that dart command line apps in Windows can use packages? What is missing in the tutorial link that I gave above?

```
C:\Development\Dartish\tmp>dir
 Volume in drive C is HDD
 Volume Serial Number is DC07-D177

 Directory of C:\Development\Dartish\tmp

06/01/2016  03:28 PM    <DIR>          .
06/01/2016  03:28 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/01/2016  03:33 PM             2,063 dcat.dart
               1 File(s)          2,063 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  74,771,554,304 bytes free

C:\Development\Dartish\tmp>dart dcat.dart -n quotes.txt
Unhandled exception:
Could not import "package:args/args.dart" from "file:///C:/Development/Dartish/tmp/dcat.dart": Could not resolve a package location for base at file:///C:/Development/Dartish/tmp/dcat.dart
#0      _asyncLoadErrorCallback (dart:_builtin:162)
#1      _asyncLoadError (dart:_builtin:584)
#2      _loadPackage (dart:_builtin:625)
#3      _loadPackage.<anonymous closure> (dart:_builtin:641)
#4      _handlePackagesReply (dart:_builtin:482)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:148)

C:\Development\Dartish\tmp>
```

Comment: What files and directories does `C:\Development\Dartish\tmp>` contain?

Comment: It only contains dcat.dart, I tried to show it in the quoted output. The tutorial does not mention pub or pubspec.yaml, is that a mistake in the tutorial? The tutorial gives specific directions after it says "Let’s take a look at the dcat sample".

Comment: It definitely is. If you use other packages you need a `pubspec.yaml` and conform to the [Pub Package Layout Conventions](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html) I guess running on the command line is not meant to be an entry level tutorial but it should work this way as well. I'll create a bug report.

Comment: I created this, but maybe you can add more info: https://github.com/dart-lang/www.dartlang.org/issues/1579

Comment: I see you already did https://github.com/dart-lang/www.dartlang.org/issues/1579 Thanks a lot.

Comment: I updated my answer with the missing steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely should not need to manually copy symbolic links or junctions.

If you run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` from the directory that contains the `pubspec.yaml` file or from within WebStorm then all these junctions should be created for you and shouldn't be modified in any way manually.

You need a pubspec.yaml file in the `tmp` directory

```
name: some_name
dependencies:
  args: any # any is discouraged but should work in this case
```

run `pub get` after the file was created

`dcat.dart` should be in `tmp/bin`

Then run from the `tmp` directory

```
dart bin/dcart.dart -n quotes.txt
```